# Yii Pre-loading form text fields from another model

Tags: yii, textfield, preloading

I am trying to pre-load the text fields from another model, I used the following code not working, here is my code.

```
public function actionCreate($id)
{                
    $id1 = Yii::app()->user->id;            
    $model = new DoctorLists;
    $prof = new Profile;
    $prof = Profile::model()->findByPk($id)

    $model->doctor_firstname = $prof->firstname;
    $model->doctor_lastname = $prof->lastname;
    $model->doctor_email = $prof->email;
    $model->doctor_mobile_no = $prof->mobile_num;
    $model->consult_no = $prof->alter_mobile_num; 

    if(isset($_POST['DoctorLists'])
    { 
        $model->attributes=$_POST['DoctorLists'];    
        if($model->save())
        {                           
            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->doctor_id));
        }
    }
    $this->render('create',array(
                                'model'=>$model,
                  ));
}
```

Comment: Pleased you fixed it. Rather than providing an answer that overwrites the question, please add your answer as an answer. We encourage this, and you can tick it as solved too. Would you do that here? You can then roll back the question to its prior state, using the editing tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a simple change in the query and got it to work and here is the  working code Now
I could preload the contents from another model

```
public function actionCreate($id)
{                
$id1 = Yii::app()->user->id;            
$model = new DoctorLists;
$prof = new Profile;
$prof = Profile::model()->find('user_id=:user_id', array(':user_id'=>$id)); 

$model->doctor_firstname = $prof->firstname;
$model->doctor_lastname = $prof->lastname;
$model->doctor_email = $prof->email;
$model->doctor_mobile_no = $prof->mobile_num;
$model->consult_no = $prof->alter_mobile_num; 

if(isset($_POST['DoctorLists'])
{ 
    $model->attributes=$_POST['DoctorLists'];    
    if($model->save())
    {                           
        $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->doctor_id));
    }
}
$this->render('create',array(
                            'model'=>$model,
              ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you missed braces for `if` statement. Try below code

```
if($id==$pid)
 {
    $model->doctor_firstname = $prof->firstname;
    $model->doctor_lastname = $prof->lastname;
    $model->doctor_email = $prof->email;
    $model->doctor_mobile_no = $prof->mobile_num;
    $model->consult_no = $prof->alter_mobile_num; 
 }
 else
 {
    throw new CHttpException(404,'The requested page does not exist.');
 }
```

Change your view code as:

```
<?php echo Chtml::textField('doctor_firstname', $model->doctor_firstname ); ?>
```

Comment: Of course true but still it is not working. I think the key makes the issue

Comment: that issue has been and I've edited the above code accordingly thanks